# print text in color in C under Cygwin

Tags: c, cygwin

I have some code in C to print out lines of text in different colors.

It's working on **Linux** using escape characters (for example [here](http://linuxgazette.net/issue65/padala.html)).
It's working on **Windows** using [SetConsoleTextAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

But my problem is when using Cygwin.
Escape characters don't work on Cygwin.
And calls to [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) always failed, and *getLastErrorText()* gives me this message:

> Incorrect function. (0x1).

So my question is: how to print text in color from a C program running in a Cygwin terminal?
Do I need to install special libraries?

Comment: What are you using as Cygwin's terminal emulator, `cmd` or `mintty`? Could yuou post code some code?

Comment: The C examples from your Linux Link work for me in Cygwin (`$TERM==cygwin`) and Cygwin-X (`$TERM==xterm`). The shell examples with `echo` work too, if you replace `^[` with `\e` and use `echo -e`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks SzG and M Oehm for you comments.

As you said, M Oehm, the linux example is working.

I found the problem in my code. I was using the color value for [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_character_attributes) instead of the ones for [Linux](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html).

For example:

```
_ftprintf(target, TEXT("%c[%d;%dm%s%c[K\n"), 
          0x1B, foreground, background, printBuffer, 0x1B);
```

The values for **foreground** and **background** were not correct.

Now it's working.